# Php array only shows my last pushed value

Tags: php, associative-array

I made a php script where you have to fill in names and their dreams, but it isn't working properly. The script has to output the names with their dreams, but i get double names or double dreams.

```
<?php
echo "How many friends should i ask for their dream?\n";
$a = readline("");
$naam = "What is your name?\n";
$droom = "What is your dream?\n";
$list = [];

if (is_numeric($a)) {
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $a; $x++) {
        echo $name;
        $c = readline("");
        echo $dream;
        $f = readline("");
        array_push($list, $c, $f);
    }
} else {
    echo "'$a' is not a number, try again.";
    exit;
}
foreach ($list as $z) {
    echo "$c has this as dream: $f \n";
    echo $z;
    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Because your output is using $c and $f, which is only going to equal the last values from the loop above. If you asked 3 friends, those variables will contain the values from the 3rd iteration when you do your next loop at the bottom to display output. They don't change after that point which is why you'll see duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off pushing both of the values into the array as one item, currently you are adding them as 2 items...

```
array_push($list, ["name" => $c, "dream" => $f]);
```

and then printing them out, you would reference the part of the array for each details...

```
foreach ($list as $z) {
    echo "{$z['name']} has this as dream: {$z['dream']} \n";
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: Or `$list = ["name" => $c, "dream" => $f];`